# Linguagem em Português para Data em Joomla, PHP

Tags: php, joomla

Estou trabalhando com um modulo de eventos em joomla e ao mostrar a data do evento o mesmo faz na linguagem Inglês. Possui o seguinte código em um dos arquivos do módulo:

```
<span itemprop="startDate"><?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->params->get('ctm_start',''), 'DATE_FORMAT_LC3'); ?></span>
        -
        <span itemprop="endDate"><?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->params->get('ctm_end',''), 'DATE_FORMAT_LC3'); ?></span>
```

Apenas por este código, eu conseguiria trazer a linguagem para português do brasil?

Comment: Pessoal, alguém da uma luz?

Comment: se minha resposta está certa, marque ela como correta, ou pelo menos dê um feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Tem mais de uma forma de fazer isso. Uma delas seria alterar direto o código que você está apontando, outra é sobrepor linguagem.

Vá em Joomla > Administrator > Extensões -> Gerenciador de Linguagens > Sopreposição e então procure por DATE_FORMAT_LC3 e substitua por um formato que você quer usar.

O significado dos dígitos podem ser vistos em http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php